# How to force Drupal not to use import on CSS?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I want to use a script to reload my CSS, but the script uses  tag and Drupal uses import for including CSS (when not using aggregation on a development site).

I tried to use hook_alter_css but apparently (using dpm function) that's not the place where the import comes from.
So, how can I override this behavior?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the [Link CSS](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_css) module to achieve this.

Or, in your own custom module, use `hook_css_alter` as described here: http://e9p.net/disable-import-tags-stylesheets-while-development-drupal

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_css_alter().
 */ 
function mymodule_css_alter(&$css) {
  $preprocess_css = variable_get('preprocess_css', TRUE);
  if (!$preprocess_css) {
    // For each item, don't allow preprocessing to disable @import.
    foreach ($css as &$item) {
      if (file_exists($item['data'])) {
        $item['preprocess'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Happens When aggregation is turned off.There is a work around if u r using a custom theme
while adding your css file in your template.php file:-

```
drupal_add_css(path_to_subtheme() .'/layout.css', 'theme', 'all', $preprocesstheme);
$preprocesstheme set it to  false (true aggration is turned on).
```

Use this method to include all css files.